# Arc length between two angles

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

As I calculate the length of the arc (green) between two angles;

[image]
I need a method like:

arc_lenght (xpos, ypos, radius, ang1, ang2) {
return arc_lenght
}

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'arc length between two angles'. Generally, you can easily find the arc length from the radius and some central angle. Also what does xpos and ypos represent? Are they the center of the circle? Cause that doesn't seem relevant to the problem.

Comment: If you have two angles, there should be two arcs on the circle that join them. Which one do you want? My guess is clockwise from the first angle to the second, is that correct? Well, they should sum up to the circumference, so if you can get one, you can get the other.

Answer (score 1):

The [arc-length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)), `l`, of a circle is equal to the angle of the arc, `θ`, in radians times the radius.

If we assume that `ang1` is in the range `[0 - ang2]` and `ang2` is in the range `[ang1 - 360]` (so `ang1` is always the smaller of the two and neither is bigger than `360`) then:

```
float angle = ang1 - ang2;
float rad = angle * PI / 180.0;
float radOutside = (2 * PI) - rad;

float arc_length = radOutside * radius;
```

I am not sure what `xpos` and `ypos` represents, but I don't think they're relevant for getting the arc length.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your angle difference. If I give you the jnputs -90 and 180, the largest arc length between them is 1.5π•radius, but this code will give the answer 3.5π•radius — including an extra full rotation.

Comment: @DMGregory That's why I made an assumption on the range of ang1 and ang2.

Comment: You could make this quite a bit shorter by assuming input in radians, too.

Comment: @WeckarE. agreed, I used degrees as input because OP's example was in degrees.